# Elements above other Ionic 4

Tags: html, sass, ionic4

I am working with Ionic 5 and I have a label with a text and a chip. And I want the label with the text on the chip, and center both vertically.

This is my HTML code...

```
<ion-card>

    <ion-item lines="none">

        <ion-label class="nombre-fecha ion-text-start" color="dark">
            <ion-text>
                <h3 class="nombre">Julia</h3>
                <p class="fecha">16 Sept, 2019</p>
            </ion-text>
        </ion-label>

        <div class="contenedor-monto">
            <ion-label class="monto ion-text-end" color="dark">$150</ion-label>
            <ion-chip color="rosa">
                <ion-label>Pasivo</ion-label>
            </ion-chip>
        </div>

    </ion-item>


</ion-card>
```

And this is my SCSS code...

```
ion-card {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6rem;
    height: 7rem;
}

.nombre {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

.fecha {
    line-height: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.contenedor-monto {
    display: flex;
}
.monto {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ion-chip {
    height: 2.5rem;
}
```

Right now I got this...

[image: Right now]

But I need this...
[image: But I need this...]

Answer (score 0):

For your solution that you have started you just need to set the flex-direction to columns. You will need to look this up to get the exact snippet, generally you need a few versions for all common browser compatibilities.

However, I would use a grid with two rows in, and then tweak it to remove whatever padding sneaks in:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid

Something like:

```
<div class="contenedor-monto">
  <ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
            <ion-label class="monto ion-text-end" color="dark">$150</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
         <ion-chip color="rosa">
            <ion-label>Pasivo</ion-label>
         </ion-chip>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</div>
```